# Mongoose discriminator and indexes

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongodb-indexes

If I setup a Model with a [discriminator key](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) mongoose automatically prefixes all queries with the discriminator key.

But if I define some keys as `index: true` the indexes that are created are not prefixed by the discriminator key. Instead they are simple indexes with a single key.

Isn't this suboptimal? Shouldn't all indexes be compound indexes of the discriminatorKey (e.G. `__t`) and the key I want to index?

And if yes should I instead of [defining indexes at the path level](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) (via `index: true`) prefer to set them like this:

```js
Event.index({ __t: 1, type: 1 });
```

Comment: Not necessarily. `QueryPlanner` analyze your query to check what index combination fits better to execute your query (check yourself: `db.event.find({__t:"foo", type:"bar"}).explain()`). So adding `__t` won't change your query performance.

Answer (score 1):

no its not suboptimal. The discriminator key makes mongoose understand which schema/model you are using and creates an instance of one for you automatically when eg. a query comes back.
Mongoose doesn't know *how* you will be using that additional key (maybe you want to query *all* of your types for a specific value? or you want to make a unique index on a name over all your types?), so creating 'basic' indexes via the path value just does what you describe, it just makes an index.

if you have the usecase that these are strongly linked, you can create [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#index-type-compound) or [sparse indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/).

Comment: thanks for your answer. So you can confirm that for performance reasons if I do have a usecase where they are strongly linked (like always only quering over a single discriminator type, not on all types) it would make sense to manually create compound indexes instead?

Comment: yes! But its always better safe [to see what mongodb is doing under the hood with your index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) and see if your indexes are correct